# Properties getProperty returning null

Tags: java

I'm having the following problem. I'm using Java properties to read some info of a file, but when I call `prop.getProperty("var")` it returns `null`. I ran out of ideas. Here is the code I have.

```
static final Properties prop = new Properties();
public JConnection(){
    try{
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("db.properties"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.info("file not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I never get the error message "file not found".

```
 public static Connection getConnection(String conType) {
    Connection conn;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
        if(model == "client"){
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("url"),prop.getProperty("usr"),prop.getProperty("pass"));  
        }else{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("url1"),prop.getProperty("usr1"),prop.getProperty("pass1")); 
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {            
        ex.printStackTrace();
        conn = null;
    }
```

When it tries to connect to the DB, `getProperty` is returning `null` as it is not found. Any ideas of what it could be or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the contents of your properties file?

Comment: Where is your property file located? Is it in class path?

Comment: No exception being thrown in the constructor?

Comment: So - you're getting NULL returned from the prop.getProoperty("url1"), rather than a NullPointerException? To me, this implies the props file file is either empty, or its contents are not what you except, or the capitalisation of the entries in the props file does not match that in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another wild guess: I noticed that both your `prop` variable and the method that's reading from it are `static`, so maybe you are using this as some sort of static utilities class without ever creating an instance of the class? In this case, you are never calling the constructor and never actually loading the properties file. Instead, you might try this:

```
static final Properties prop = new Properties();
static {
    try{
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("db.properties"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.info("file not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, i deleted my constructor and add the code above. But is it "correct" to do that ? looks like a hotfix.

Comment: Well, you could also make it a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object, but I think this is perfectly okay.

Answer (score 3):

You have a static field (prop), but you initialize it in a constructor. This means if you consult your prop object before you construct any object of JConnection, prop will not be initialized.

You can try something like this:

```
public class JConecction {
    static final Properties prop = new Properties();

    static {
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("db.properties"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.info("file not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, Excuse me!, you're right. The problem is in the content of file

Comment: @BlackSlash, I have edited my comment in order to not create confusion. Thanks!

Comment: So, you edited this to basically the same thing that I answered before?

Comment: Yes, I saw it after apply my edition :-(. But I was between edit it again or delete it, and I decided not delete. I hope this don't disturb you ;-)

Regards,

Comment: No, it's okay. I was a bit grumpy first, because it looked as if your answer was there first (older answer timestamp) but that's okay. Never mind. :-)